# react native - Check the render method of Navigator

Tags: react-native

I am new at react native and trying to understand the use of navigation there....

found this example code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, Navigator } from 'react-native';

import Apple from './app';
import Orange from './app'

class AwesomeProject extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Navigator
                initialRoute={{screen: 'Apple'}}
                renderScene={(route, nav) => {return this.renderScene(route, nav)}}
            />
        )
        }

    renderScene(route,nav) {
        switch (route.screen) {
            case "Apple":
                return <Apple navigator={nav} />
            case "Orange":
                return <Orange navigator={nav} />
        }
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => AwesomeProject);
```

Also created:

Apple.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';

export default class Apple extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Apple</Text>
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.goOrange.bind(this)}>
                    <Text>Go to Orange</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
        )
    }

    goOrange() {
        console.log("go to orange");
        this.props.navigator.push({ screen: 'Orange' });
    }
}
```

But I am getting this error for some reason...
why?

this is the error message I am getting in the emulator

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `Navigator`.
instantiateReactComponent
    index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false:23290:16
updateChildren
    index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false:23171:58
_reconcilerUpdateChildren
    index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false:22945:44
_updateChildren
    index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false:23015:54
updateChildren
```

Comment: What does your Orange component look like? I literally copy pasted your code into an online emulator and [it works there](https://snack.expo.io/Bk4dyylRg).

Comment: Just reset the emulator.